# Dummy variable manipulation based on date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a input dataset as follows:

```
date      event         A

2015-07-15  A     1
2015-07-16  A     1
.......
2015-07-22  A     1
2015-07-23  A     1   
........
2015-07-26  A     1
```

Here A is the dummy/indicator variable for event A. I want to further subset the dummy variable, where your A_new(new indicator variable) is 1 if date is in the range 2015-07-15 and 2015-07-22, else it remains 0.

```
Output is:
date       event        A  A_new

2015-07-15  A           1   1
2015-07-16  A           1   1
.......
2015-07-22  A           1   1
2015-07-23  A           1   0   
........
2015-07-26  A           1   0
```

My code looks like:

```
df['A_new']=df['A']

df.loc[~((df.date >='2015-07-15') & (df.date <='2015-07-22')),'A_new']=0
```

But still I am not get desired result. Just wonder my logic is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Simplier solution is cast boolean mask to `int` - so `True` are `1` and `False` are `0`:

```
df['A_new'] = ((df.date >='2015-07-15') & (df.date <='2015-07-22')).astype(int)
print (df)
        date event  A  A_new
0 2015-07-15     A  1      1
1 2015-07-16     A  1      1
2 2015-07-22     A  1      1
3 2015-07-23     A  1      0
4 2015-07-26     A  1      0
```

Another solution with [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df['A_new'] = df.date.between('2015-07-15','2015-07-22').astype(int)
print (df)
        date event  A  A_new
0 2015-07-15     A  1      1
1 2015-07-16     A  1      1
2 2015-07-22     A  1      1
3 2015-07-23     A  1      0
4 2015-07-26     A  1      0
```

As [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957565/dummy-variable-manipulation-based-on-date-range/41957644?noredirect=1#comment71096539_41957644) pointed if need values by column `A` multiple by `A` (thank you):

```
print (df)
         date event  A
0  2015-07-15     A  1
1  2015-07-16     A  6
2  2015-07-22     A  2
3  2015-07-23     A  1
4  2015-07-26     A  1

df['A_new'] = df.date.between('2015-07-15','2015-07-22').astype(int).mul(df.A)
print (df)
         date event  A  A_new
0  2015-07-15     A  1      1
1  2015-07-16     A  6      6
2  2015-07-22     A  2      2
3  2015-07-23     A  1      0
4  2015-07-26     A  1      0
```

---

Solution with [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['A_new'] = df.A.where(df.date.between('2015-07-15','2015-07-22'), 0)
print (df)
         date event  A  A_new
0  2015-07-15     A  1      1
1  2015-07-16     A  6      6
2  2015-07-22     A  2      2
3  2015-07-23     A  1      0
4  2015-07-26     A  1      0
```

Comment: if `A_new` is supposed to be a subset of `A` and there were other events, you'd want `df.A * df.date.between('2015-07-15','2015-07-22')`

Comment: @piRSquared Can you please tell that why you asked jezreal to multiply by column itself?

Comment: @user2906657 It's a technique to multiply a boolean series to turn it on or off depending on if the booleans are true or false.  Multiplying `df.date.between('2015-07-15','2015-07-22')` (a series of trues and falses) by `df.A` returns a series equal to `A` when True, `0` otherwise.  This is a great answer.  Don't forget to select it as the chosen answer if it solved your problem.